# Is it possible to set multiple in-app notifications for an application through clevertap for same period of time?

Tags: android, set, message, clevertap

Is it possible to set multiple in-app notifications for an application through clevertap for same period of time? I am setting 2 in-app messages from clevertap for my application. But I am able to see only the old one. Both is set for lifetime period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-app notifications are set to particular system/custom events. If we take an example where an in-app notification is to be shown at the launch of the app. The campaign will be created for the system event `App Launched`. If another campaign is created for the same event, the campaign will wait for the first one to be stopped before it can start.

Hope this answer your question. If you have any other concerns/questions you can reach out to us at support@clevertap.com

Comment: thanks +1 the answer is pretty clear to solve my query.